# using shell script command output

Tags: shell

I am writing a simple shell script that fetches output from one command and uses it in another.

```
 app=$(./twiddle.sh  -u $1 -p $2 query jboss.web.deployment:* | grep $3)
 doop=$(./twiddle.sh -u $1 -p $2 invoke jboss.system:MainDeployer $4 $app)
```

++ ./twiddle.sh -u admin -p password invoke jboss.system:MainDeployer stop $'jboss.web.deployment:war=worker.war,id=1518231766\r'

I see in the above commands that the app is coming of value:

```
$'jboss.web.deployment:war=worker.war,id=1518231766\r'
```

But if I do echo $app  then I am not seeing the quotes and \r appended, How can I ensure app is sent without quotes as an input to another command? I am not sure where the problem is - I cannot see this as the output when I execute the commands outside of shell.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed will work nicely for this:

```
sh  -u $1 -p $2 query jboss.web.deployment:* | grep $3 | sed 's/\'//g' | sed 's/\r//g'
```

Comment: `grep pattern | sed 's/from/to/g'` is often not needed, as sed has a built-in grep: `sed -ne '/pattern/s/from/to/gp'` often saves a fork. And sed can even do several substitutions saving yet another fork...

Answer (score 0):

```
doop=$(./twiddle.sh -u $1 -p $2 invoke jboss.system:MainDeployer $4 "$app")
```

You should use echo with quotes if you don't want the contents be interpreted by the shell. If you don't want characters like `'` be interpreted too, use printf: `printf '%s' "$app"`

Comment: No adding quotes did not remove the problem.

Comment: Did you try the second thing, with printf?
Like this:

doop=$(./twiddle.sh -u $1 -p $2 invoke jboss.system:MainDeployer $4 "``printf '%s' "$app"``")